# The verbs of learning: 勉強する, 習う and 学ぶ

Tags: word-choice, verbs, wago-and-kango

How are the following verbs which are related to learning different to each other?

- 勉強する
- 習う
- 学ぶ

Comment: dont forget 覚える！

Comment: @Gerard 覚える is simply "to remember/memorize". Learning is more than memorizing ;)

Comment: @Lukman 覚える is actually sometimes used with the meaning of learning, for instance many people say 仕事を覚える for learning a new job, even non-repetitive jobs.

Comment: You could also add 身につける to the list, for when learning by yourself, as opposed to learning from a teacher/mentor (学ぶ).

Comment: related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18645/differences-between-%E5%8B%89%E5%BC%B7%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-%E7%BF%92%E3%81%86-%E5%AD%A6%E3%81%B6-and-%E5%AD%A6%E7%BF%92%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**学ぶ**

The original character is: 學

Meaning 2 hands writing characters and teaching a child

学ぶ is to imitate (or assimilate and repeat) what the teacher says. Study a subject from a teacher.

Most meaningful examples:

> 私たちは学ぶために学校に行く (We go to school to
> learn.)
>
> 私は日本語を学びはじめてから４０年になる (It is forty
> years since I began the study of
> Japanese.)
>
> 英語を学び始めた (I started to learn English)

**習う**

This character is composed of 羽 (wings) and 白 (clear/understand)

It shows how to learn by repeated practice like a small bird learning to fly.

Most meaningful examples:

> バイクの乗り方を習う (learning to ride a bike)
>
> 車の運転を習っていない (I haven't learned to drive - I can't drive)
>
> 書道を習うのは楽しい (Learning calligraphy is fun.)

**勉強する**

勉 = make an effort
強 = powerful

It came to be used for "to study" but outside the class. Nobody teaches you, you "force" yourself to study something, do your homework, assimilate a lesson...etc.

Most meaningful examples:

> 先生は私にもっと勉強するようにと言った (The teacher told
> me to study harder.)
>
> これからもっと勉強します (I'll study harder in
> future)

*Examples taken from EDICT and organized for this answer in the correct categories.*

Comment: How about 学習する? :p

Comment: @phirru: You're taught how to fly by a school teacher ;)

Comment: To quote my philosophy of education prof, the difference between 学and 習う can be described as the difference between "*knowing that* cesium is an element" and "*knowing how* to ride a bike" -- obtaining knowledge vs. acquiring a skill.

Comment: @Chocolate Why is there に in "先生は私にもっと勉強するよう**に**と言った"?

Comment: @starckman The と is quotative, and 「～するように」 is imperative. Would [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/90307/9831) help? (「～～するよう言った」「～～するように言った」「～～するようにと言った」"ordered to do~~" all sound okay, but 「～～するようと言った」 sounds wrong. I can't explain why 「～～するようと言った」（先生は私にもっと勉強するようと言った） sounds wrong, so maybe you can post it as a new question?) -- P.S. Why ask me? This is not my post.

Comment: `It shows how to learn by repeated practice` `車の運転を習っていない - I can't drive`  ←  先生か誰かに指導してもらわないで「運転を習う」とか「書道を習う」とか言いません。 `acquiring a skill.` ←  学校や塾で数学や国語などの教科(実技科目でない)でも「佐藤先生に習っている」「山田先生に習った」って言います。

Comment: I understand that と marks direct quote, but I don't understand what に means here. I think よう expresses conjectural meaning, a sort of polite command

Answer (score 7):

勉強する is 'study' and is usually applied to school/literature.

習う is 'learn' and is usually applied to things like learning instruments or skills.

学ぶ carries a more 'in depth' meaning to it, and is usually applied to things like a vocation or 'years of study in XYZ'.

勉強する is the most common and is fairly good at being used in place of the others.

Comment: I just don't thing that "勉強" applies as well as you say to other things. If you say "today, I learned a new word", you'll *never* say 勉強, will you? I think that 習う (and to a slightly lesser extent 学ぶ) have a broader use.