# Best word choice "to learn"

Tags: word-choice

I want to say I am learning, but not in a study/classroom/teacher kind of way, but dictionary definitions have me confused.

- 習う　→　to learn (to take classes in)
- 覚える　→　to memorize/remember, (to learn?)
- 学ぶ　→　to study? take classes in something?
- 勉強する　→　to study

Until now, I've been using 習う、but based on how frequently 日本人 use 覚える、I just feel like that's probably the one to go with...but I don't know. The other two are definitely not what I want.

example sentence:

> 私は仕事で色んなことを覚えてる。勉強になる。
>   I am learning various things at work, its quite informative.

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18658/9831

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Differences between 勉強する、習う、学ぶ and 学習する?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18645/differences-between-%e5%8b%89%e5%bc%b7%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b-%e7%bf%92%e3%81%86-%e5%ad%a6%e3%81%b6-and-%e5%ad%a6%e7%bf%92%e3%81%99%e3%82%8b)

Comment: I don't think it duplicate because 覚える isn't covered in that post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well

習う: is learning but the real meaning is closer to: to be taught by a teacher, so you are learning.

覚える : is Memorize/learning, but here is the catch, the meaning is that you memorize something because you did it again and again, you didn't have to really study to learn it, you just repeat it again and again.

学ぶ : Means deep learning, eg studying japanese but not N5 or N4 something more advanced like >N3, we use manabu to express that we are really deep into studying

勉強する: Also means to study, eg studying for an exam, studying not very deep, just studying for passing a test of completing something