# Is the sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, sentence

I want to say a phrase “I have learnt a lot of words by heart”.  Is it correct to say: 単語をたくさん習いました。 I mean is it the way native speaker would say it?

Comment: Have you tried looking up "learning by heart" or "to learn by heart"?

Comment: Read [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18658/5010) carefully. 習いました is a natural sentence but it does not necessarily mean you've successfully memorized many words.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer cleared a lot of points for me.

Comment: But strictly speaking none of those answers contain the answer for this question, I guess...