# How to say in Japanese "I want to learn driving a car"?

Tags: translation, sentence

I am currently learning Japanese, I am still a beginner and right now I am trying to say something like "I want to learn driving a car" or "I want to learn how to drive a car". I was trying to use 車を運転する combined with 習いたい but I don't know how to connect these two words so it makes sense.

Comment: The most generic expression is 車の運転を覚えたい (verb: おぼえる). 習う means to learn something from a teacher. 学ぶ is closer to "to study" or "to learn a lesson".

Comment: @user4092  You should check out this question, I think you have 習うand 学ぶ mixed up. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1732/the-verbs-of-learning-%E5%8B%89%E5%BC%B7%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-%E7%BF%92%E3%81%86-and-%E5%AD%A6%E3%81%B6/1739#1739

Comment: ^ `I think you have 習うand 学ぶ mixed up` はぁ・・user4092さんは日本語母語話者なんですけどね・・ `習う means to learn something from a teacher. 学ぶ is closer to "to study" or "to learn a lesson"` 私もそう思いますけど・・

Comment: 知らなくて、失礼しました。前の答えに学ぶは教師のことも関係あるって書いてあるんですが、習うに対しては教師のことは書いていないんです。コッピした答えは少しでもmisleadingでしょうか？私はたぶん学ぶと習うのニュアンスが分かりません。@Chocolate

Comment: `mi‌​sleadingでしょうか` さあ、どうでしょう・・きっと「学」の漢字は、もともとそういう意味なんでしょうね・・`学‌​ぶと習うのニュアンスが分かりません` それなら、これなんか超おススメです！ →　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18658/9831

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this.

1. **車の運転を習いたい**. A suru-verb like 運転 can work as a noun if you dropped the する part. 運転 means *driving* all by itself. Literally, "I want to learn driving of a car."
2. **車を運転する方法を習いたい**. 方法 is a noun meaning "method/way", and 車を運転する is used as a [(gapless) relative clause](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/5010) that modifies 方法. Literally, "I want to learn the way of driving a car."
3. **どうやって車を運転するか習いたい**. Here どうやって is "how", and どうやって車を運転するか is an [embedded question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13038/5010) meaning "how I (can) drive a car". Literally, "I want to learn how I (can) drive a car."

The first one is the simplest and most natural way if you just want to say you want a driver's license. The other two are wordy and usually unnecessary (but they can help you to learn the Japanese grammar).

Comment: is there a reason you said を習いたい as opposed to が習いたい?

Comment: @A.Ellett Good question, according to [this PDF](http://www.ritsumei.ac.jp/acd/cg/lt/rb/599/599pdf/higasiya.pdf), を～たい and が～たい are sometimes interchangeable, while younger people tend to prefer the former. But somehow I strongly feel 車の運転が習いたい is ungrammatical. ケーキが食べたい and テレビが見たい are okay, of course. Hmm...I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can express that like this:

> 車を運転することが出来るようになりたい: "I want to be able to drive a car"

or you could say something like this:

> 車を運転することを学びたい: "I want to learn how to drive a car"

For making these expressions you need to learn how to make a verb or a sentence into a noun with こと or の. More information in Minna No Nihongo Shokyuu II Lesson 38 or the youtube video "Japanese verbs into nouns - Japanese in 5! #25" from the Japanese from zero channel