# マリーと日本語を勉強 / Studying with Marie. Is this right?

Tags: learning

マリーと日本語を勉強 or マリーと一緒に日本語を勉強する ?

I just started learning kanji, so i'm not sure which one would be the correct way to say this.

I'm trying to write "Studying with Marie"

Comment: Is your question about kanji or is it about how to say "studying with Marie"? I'm not sure what you are asking about. Also, "studying with Marie" isn't a full sentence. What do you want to say in full?

Comment: This is the headline of something. It isn't supposed to be a full sentence. It's about the kanji.

Comment: The kanji are fine.

Comment: Ok, which one would be more correct? To your standards

Comment: As far as kanji go, they're both fine. As far as grammar and the best way to express the idea as a title, I don't know the answer. But that has nothing to do with the kanji.  I'm in the middle of asking my own question to clarify exactly this point.

Comment: This is a fine title as answered by naruto. (short and clear = succinct title) = the long title: マリーと(一緒に)日本語を勉強(する) short title:  マリーと日本語を勉強. (as answered by naruto as well)

Answer (score 1):

マリーと一緒に日本語を勉強する ("I study Japanese together with Marie") is perfectly valid as an ordinary sentence, but it's unnatural as the title of a website, a book, etc. On the other hand, マリーと日本語を勉強 ("Studying Japanese with Marie") is much better as a title, but it sounds too blunt and clumsy as an ordinary sentence. Your kanji usage is fine.

There is still room for improving マリーと日本語を勉強. マリーと日本語**の**勉強 looks better than your attempt because 勉強 can work as a simple noun. And マリーと学ぶ日本語 would look even better and natural, and actually there are many books titled in this pattern. The first three real examples I found on Japanese Amazon were: "SNOOPYと学ぶアメリカ文化", "メイドと学ぶ商会経営" (NSFW) and "わかばちゃんと学ぶWebサイト制作の基本".

Comment: ok ,thank you so much for this in depth clarification! :)

Comment: @naruto Isn't 学ぶ implies that you study in a classroom, like taking a class? while 勉強 implies that you take liberty to learn by yourself? Regarding マリーと日本語の勉強 -> isn't this kinda like: (self-) Study of Japanese with Mary? I understand the cultural difference where Japanese students will be more usually found in a classroom when learning a foreign language (though a few are homeschooled/taking private course - usually adult)

Comment: @Flonne 学ぶ is perfectly fine in the title of a self-learning material. (Maybe you're confusing it with 習う?) There is a [difference between 勉強する and 学ぶ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18645/5010), but IMHO 学ぶ sounds better in this case.

Comment: @Flonne [ah yes, that word 習う,sorry, my mistake] (so the part that explains 学ぶ = take lessons in isn't considered as 'normal usage' ? Because I get this impression, or it's just me? (just like when you study at school with a tense atmosphere and strict teacher ready to yell or shame you when you make a mistake)

Comment: Also more explanation, especially in 学ぶ part > https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1732/the-verbs-of-learning-%E5%8B%89%E5%BC%B7%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-%E7%BF%92%E3%81%86-and-%E5%AD%A6%E3%81%B6

Comment: You can safely use 学ぶ when you learn something from a book or a website. As [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/18658/5010) says, 勉強 is like *study* and focuses on the effort, while 学ぶ is like *learn/master* and focuses on the result.

Comment: @naruto If the title were just "Studying with Marie" so you couldn't make a relative clause using 日本語, would マリーとの勉強 be the best option?

Comment: @user3856370 Yes, but it may sound too "serious" depending on the implication. Alternatively マリーとお勉強 may look more casual or "romantic".