# Verb form for titles and section headings

Tags: grammar

I read [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/63001/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A8%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%82%92%E5%8B%89%E5%BC%B7-studying-with-marie-is-this-right) and realised that I don't know what the natural way to make a title/section heading is.

Supposing I had a section in a science report which was "Designing the experiment". What would be natural ways to write this? Here are some guesses:

1) 実験を設計している
2) 実験を設計していること
3) 実験の設計

1) feels wrong to me. I'm not at all sure about 2). 3) Seems okay but it only works because I used a する verb.

Presumably the context is important too. Adding  こと in 2) sounds formal. I guess I wouldn't see that in a magazine headline. What about "Eating in fancy restaurants" as the title of a magazine article. Would the verb be 食べている, 食べる or some other conjugation?

In summary, how do you write "Doing X" as a headline/title/section heading in formal and informal contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suru-verbs are also nouns, so something like 実験計画 or 実験の計画 should be enough. (設計 is usually for product design.) Non-suru-verbs are uncommon in scientific articles in the first place. You should use 摂取/摂食/食事 instead of 食べること, 睡眠 instead of 寝ること, 閲覧/観察/確認/etc instead of 見ること, and so on. In addition, some established [nouns formed from masu-stem](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010) are suitable in technical contexts, too.

Comment: Maybe it's just because I've never seen them before, but 摂取 and 摂食 look like difficult words. Would they really be used for a light-hearted magazine article? In general though, your advice is to avoid using verbs, right?