# difference between ように言う and ようにと言う

Tags: grammar, particle-と

I have bumped into this sentence during my immersion:

> なんでも　離婚した君のお父さんが娘の君が困った時に渡すようにとお母さんに言ったらしい。

Why in this case is ようにと言う and not ように言う?
Is this a direct quotation instead of imperative defined by ように言う?

Answer (score 1):

It's a direct quote.  Like when folks say things like わすれないように or かぜをひかないように.  That's the complete utterance.

So, what the father said to the mother was just the words 渡すように, "[please] hand it over".  (Without more context it's a bit hard to say more than that.)

This is just an abbreviated form of

> 渡すようにしてください

So for example わすれないように, "[please] remember" (lit "[please] don't forget").  かぜをひかないように, "[please] keep healthy" (lit "[please] don't catch a cold")

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. What’s the meaning of ように in this case?

Comment: It's just a mild way of making a command.  Essentially it would be ...ようにしてください.  But the してください part is omitted.  So, it just means "Please..."